# Optimizing memory usage in applying a furrr function to a large list of tibbles: experiencing unexpected memory increase

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, purrr, furrr

I am currently working on a task that involves applying a function to a fairly extensive list of tibbles, comprising approximately 30,000 elements. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
plan(multisession, workers=20)

hpar$input_df %>%
    group_by(key) %>% 
    group_split() %>%
    future_walk(sf_do_all_one_series, 
                hpar$df_stockout_decaying, 
                hpar$out_path, 
                hpar$out_prefix, 
                .env_globals = empty_env())
```

The function `sf_do_all_one_series`, which is called within the future_walk function, has the following structure:

```
sf_do_all_one_series <- function(df_1, df_stockout_decaying, out_path, out_prefix){
  
  key <- df_1 %>% distinct(key) %>% pull()
  
  do_stuff(df_1, df_stockout_decaying) %>% 
    do_more_stuff() %>% 
    write.table(file=paste0(out_path, out_prefix, "_", key, ".csv"), quote=FALSE, sep='\t', row.names=FALSE)
  
  invisible()
}
```

The `hpar$input_df` tibble consists of approximately 3 million records, and its size, calculated using `object.size(.)`, is around 202 MB. On the other hand, `hpar$df_stockout_decaying` is a small tibble containing constant values. Lastly, `hpar$out_path` and `hpar$out_prefix` are character strings.

The issue I'm encountering is that the memory usage during this process shows a DRAMATIC increase over time, as if some intermediate output is being saved. I'm seeking guidance on understanding the potential cause of this memory increase and any possible solutions.

I have made several attempts to address the memory issue but haven't been successful so far. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Removing intermediate objects: I tried minimizing the use of intermediate objects within the code to reduce memory consumption.
2. Garbage collector: I also explicitly called the garbage collector using the `gc()` function to free up any unused memory.
3. `.env_globals = empty_env()`: Although I don't believe the `.env_globals = empty_env()` parameter is necessary for future_walk, I still tried including it in the hope that it might have an impact.

Unfortunately, despite implementing these measures, memory usage has not shown any noticeable improvement.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights to help resolve this issue.

Comment: I can't point articulate exactly why, but I suspect that `write.table` may be the issue. Try [fwrite](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.8/topics/fwrite)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Actually i do not think the problem is the file writing, even without writing anything I was experiencing the same issue. `mcl_apply` seems to be less memory greedy